# Access is Denied when trying to add a resource to C++/CLI project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

I am trying to add a resource to my C++/CLI project. I am working with Visual Studio 2012. TFS 2013.

- Right Click on the project => Add => Resource => I get the error.

Error:

> The operation could not be completed. Access is denied.

I do not understand why I am getting this error. I don't know how to fix it. So far:

- I checked-out the entire project (Project and all its files)
- I removed the "Read-Only" mark of the folder and all the files inside it.

I can add other files and edit everything, but for some reason I can not add resources.

I can edit the resource file in Notepad, so I don't know what else to do. (I even rebooted just in case).

I can add resources to a C++ Native Library I have in the same project.

**What else could be causing this error?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the Resource file was somehow corrupted. After trying different approaches, I kept getting the same error, while I could easily add resources to other projects.

I deleted the resource file and everything related, and created everything from scratch and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

This happened to me because I had still opened the resource (*.rc) file in the Resource Editor and/or Text Editor. As soon as I closed it, I was able to add resources again.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows option in the menu.
Windows->click on close all documents.

It worked for me later you can open all your project files again and you can now add resources.

Comment: not sure, but it does not really look like a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows option in the menu of Visual Studio. Windows->click on close all documents.

It worked for me. Later you can open all your project files again and you can now click on your *.rc file, you can now see all your folders.

The answer in "Answers" which is similar to this answer is submitted by me with different userID.

Thank you